# how to remove the /[ defolt lang tag] from url using nextjs?

Tags: next.js, i18next

How do I make a redirect in next.js and i18n? I want it not to be possible to go to /en en to throw either on / or on 404.

```
dont path : /en
```

My next.config.js

```
       i18n: {
        // strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        localeDetection: false,
        locales: ['en', 'ru', 'uk'],
       },

      async rewrites() {
     return [{
        source: '/en',
        destination: '/404',
    },
    ]
   }


    async redirects() {
    return [
        {

            source: '/en',
            destination: '/404',
            permanent: false,
            locale: false,
        },
     ]
     },
```